# $Y,Z$ be linear subspaces of a Banach space $X$ ; $Y$ be finite dimensional , $Z$ closed in $X$ ; is $Y+Z$ closed in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be linear subspaces of a Banach space $X$ , such that $ Y$ is finite-dimensional and $Z$ is closed in $X$ , then is $Y +Z$ also closed in $X$ ?

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548840/let-e-be-a-banach-space-prove-that-the-sum-of-two-closed-subspaces-is-closed

Comment: @Seven : Is the fact that the main space is Banach , needed anywhere ?

Comment: Nice point. I don't see it being used anywhere in the first proof. Perhaps you should wait for a comment on the original answer.